# Jenkins Deployment Not Visible

Tags: php, symfony, jenkins, mercurial

I have created a build via Jenkins which was successful. But my changes are still not visible.

Do I need to point my domain to `/var/lib/Jenkins/workspace/project` ?? However I tried doing that it gives a 403 error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with Jenkins? What is your Jenkins configuration like?

Comment: I have a domain abc.com. My configuration pulled all the changes from a Mercurial repository. The jenkins build tells me, it has successfully build all the stuff and I can see my latest commit message on jenkins as well. But I am wondering how can I c the changes on abc.com ?? On the server I have code at /var/lib/Jenkins/workspace/project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is no repository viewer, thus does not provide that functionality itself - you need to install one.

However there are plug-ins available which allow *linking* to them from withing Jenkins:

- You can allow browsing the current working dir. But that doesn't give you any changes, though, just the current state.
- You can use a plug-in which allows to link the build to the corresponding revisions in your repository viewer (e.g. the mercurial plugin allows to link to all kinds of VCS viewers which support mercurial, similar is available for other VCS, too)